# Java and LibGDX Framework count phone steps?

Tags: java, libgdx, step

I need to count user step in my game to move player character.
My player should move while someone is walking, but after I use System.out.print on numstep its still zero. 
 How can i count my step in Java and the LibGDX Framework?

```
 public class PlayerBros extends Game {

        public  int step=0;
    }
    public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements SensorEventListener,StepListener {

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
            accel = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            simpleStepDetector = new StepDetector();
            simpleStepDetector.registerListener(this);

            sensorManager.registerListener(AndroidLauncher.this, accel, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
            config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
            playerBros=new PlayerBros();
            numSteps = playerBros.step;
            initialize(playerBros, config);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                simpleStepDetector.updateAccel(
                        event.timestamp, event.values[0], event.values[1], event.values[2]);
                System.out.print("AndroidLauncher: "+numSteps);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void step(long timeNs) {
            numSteps++;

        }

    }
    public class PlayScreen implements Screen {
    private PlayerBros game;

     public void handleInput(float dt){
     player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(game.step,y), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
            hud.marioLabel.setText(" "+game.step);
            System.out.print("PlayScreen: "+game.step);

     }
        public void update(float dt){
          handleInput(dt);
    }

    }
```

Comment: You would have to make it yourself. In the Android module, use something like this http://www.gadgetsaint.com/android/create-pedometer-step-counter-android/ in order to make the step counter.

Comment: I have followed that tutorial and now I want to apply my step to my game character to make it move. But for some reason my game character wont move and I think I am passing my step from AndroidLauncher to PlayScreen wrong. Can someone help me?

Comment: You need to provide context with code, preferably within the post itself instead of through links, and actions you have taken to debug. Did you try using System.out to verify the steps number? How about a System.out on every step?